# Graphic median filter in C++

Tags: filter, median, graphic

I have to write an application in C++ that realized graphic median filter. It should based on PPM or PGM files (P2 standard). Program was written by me but the image after filtering is incorrect.

Here is the output image: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/850/75ww.jpg

I am pretty sure that reading and writing to file is correct because when i exclude filter the source and output image are the same, so error should be in filter.

Here you can find all methods for filter class: http://pastebin.com/RuJMP2RY and class:

```
#ifndef FILTER_H
#define FILTER_H

class filter
{
    int **imageMap, **outputMap, *part;
    int x, y, sampleSize, newX, newY;
    void resizeMap();
    void createEmptyTable();
    void fillZeros();
    void importMap();
    void getPart(int, int);
    int calcMedian();
    int calcAvg();
    void sortList();
    void switchValue(int mValue, int startX, int startY);
    void exportMap();
    void filterImage(int, int);
public:
    filter(int x, int y, int size, int **matrix);
    int **getImageMap();
};
```

I will be realy gratefull if you will find and error in my code.

Comment: You need to reduce the problem to a small amount of relevant code and include it in your question.

Comment: From a quick scan of the code it looks like sortList is completely broken, and there may also be issues with how you handle the image borders.

Comment: you need to narrow it down to a better defined question

Comment: sortList is OK because it is bubble sort and it returns correctly sorted list. I have no idea how to better define a question because I don't know where exactly error is.

Comment: No, sortList is *NOT* OK - it has at least two serious and glaringly obvious bugs - you really need to learn to test and debug your code.

Comment: OK, you were right, I have change it but still it returns wrong application. I will tray to flat arrays but I think that it dosen't resolve my problem.

Comment: You have a number of problems in your code - you need to take a *methodical approach* to finding and fixing the bugs - don't assume that just because something appears to work some of the time that it's bug-free. Learn to use your debugger and be *systematic* about debugging.